# The in-radius works different in Netlogo 6.1.0 than in previous version

Tags: netlogo

I have the following code which creates a grid of agents and place links between pairs if they are in a distance of interference.

```
breed [ readers reader ]
undirected-link-breed [ rris rri ]

globals [
  interf-rri-radius
  num-readers
  distance-var-x
  distance-var-y
  readers-per-row
  readers-per-column
  num-checkouts
]


to setup
  ca
  setup-globals
  ask patches [ set pcolor blue - 3 ]
  spawn-by-row-col
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-globals
  set  interf-rri-radius 1005
  set num-readers 40
  set distance-var-x 12
  set distance-var-y 22
  set readers-per-row 8
  set readers-per-column 5
  set num-checkouts 0
end

to spawn-by-row-col
  let half-step 0.5 * distance-var-x
  let d-vals ( range ( min-pxcor + half-step ) ( min-pxcor + (readers-per-row * distance-var-x)) distance-var-x )

  let dc-vals ( range ( min-pxcor + half-step ) ( min-pycor + (readers-per-column * distance-var-y)) distance-var-y )
  show dc-vals
  ; Create an empty list to build into
  let possible-coords []

  ; For each possible vertical value, map all horizontal values in order and
  ; combine these into an ordered list starting at the lowest px and py coords

  foreach dc-vals [
    d ->
    set possible-coords ( sentence possible-coords map [ i -> (list i d) ] d-vals )
  ]

  show (word "possible-coords = " possible-coords)
  ; Use the number of readers to sublist the possible coordinates, and
  ; create a turtle at each of the coordinate combinations left.
  let max-positions length possible-coords
  if max-positions > (num-readers + num-checkouts) [ set max-positions (num-readers + num-checkouts) ]
  let use-coords sublist possible-coords num-checkouts max-positions
  foreach use-coords [
    coords ->
    create-readers 1 [
      setxy item 0 coords item 1 coords
      set shape "square 2"
      set size 2
      set color 15
    ]
  ]
  ask readers [ create-rris-with other readers in-radius (interf-rri-radius / 10) ]
end
```

The neighbors of reader 0 are

```
show [sort [who] of rri-neighbors] of reader 0
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
```

However, the distance between reader 0 and reader 39 is

```
show [distance reader 0] of reader 39
121.6552506059644
```

and the connection radius is 1005/10= 100.5 so they should not be connected with an `rri` link.

*Notice*, I use a origin-centered world of -50 to 50 in X and Y dimensions.

I have tested the code in previous Netlogo version 6.0.4 and the reader 39 is not a neighbour of the reader 0.
I do not know what can be the problem. I believe is the new version but I would like to be sure.

Comment: where is the connection radius of 1005/10 calculated in the code?

Comment: @JenB I have used in-radius ( interface-rri-radius / 10) at the end of the first group of code.

Comment: @JenB I have to add the world dimensions is a not toroidal world of -50 to 50 in x and y.

Comment: There were optimizations to the `in-radius` primitive in 6.1.0, so it is possible a bug was introduced there.  Would you be willing to post your complete code here, or otherwise to email a copy and explanation to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu?  The NetLogo team can take a look and try to find the root cause.

Comment: @Jasper Yes. I did not know the Email address. I will report the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, there is a confirmed bug with `in-radius` in the NetLogo 6.1.0 release, and the details are in [the bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1756).

The issue only affects `in-radius` when used in a non-wrapped world, and only when used on turtles, and only when used with a radius that's a significant % of the world width.  If you're using a world with wrapping, or using `in-radius` with patches, or using a small radius relative to the world size, your data will be correct and you don't need the below workaround.

As a workaround if your model is affected, you can use a simple user-defined NetLogo procedure in your model until the fix is published.  It's not going to be super-fast if your having turtles calculate `in-radius` many times per tick, but if you have few turtles or are just using it during setup, it should be okay:

```
to-report temp-in-radius [agentset r]
  report agentset with [ distance myself <= r ]
end
```

Then, instead of `create-rris-with other readers in-radius (interf-rri-radius / 10)` you would do `create-rris-with (temp-in-radius other readers (interf-rri-radius / 10))`.

Or more generally, instead of something like `count other turtles in-radius 5` would become `count temp-in-radius (other turtles) 5`.